# Correct way to use boost::asio::streambuf for reading and writing

Tags: c++, asynchronous, networking, boost, boost-asio

I have data stream in specific format, which I need read/write within network. Currently, I use `boost::asio::streambuf` with the async_* functions in the boost::asio. Sometimes, I need read all data which available on the ssl socket as soon as possible, but I don't understand how I can do it correctly.

Now I am reading data from the ssl socket like this:

```
// m_ssl_stream is ssl socket stream
// m_buffer is a boost::asio::streambuf 
boost::asio::async_read(ssl_stream, m_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), callback);
```

But there is a problem. For example, I have  20.000 available bytes in the ssl socket, but I can't read all of this data at one read operation because completion condition `boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1)` returns usually 512 bytes. As result, I am reading all available data in 35-40 read operations instead of 1-2.

The m_buffer is also used in other async operations, which can be scheduled for reading from same data stream with other async_* functions. For example, after read data using `boost::asio::async_read(ssl_stream, m_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), callback);` I can "go" to read http headers using `boost::beast::http::async_read_header` if state of my stream signals for that. In this case, headers MUST be present in the `boost::asio::streambuf` for successful reading headers in other async operation.

I think it can be done using m_ssl_stream.async_read_some operation, but this operation cannot accept `boost::asio::streambuf` as the buffer.

Does anyone have an idea how I can implement this?

Comment: How come you're combining `async_read_header` and manual reads? That would not normally be necessary with HTTP, unless you are going to great length to avoid using Beast to read the body, and making up for it "in secret". That's complication that you probably don't need.

Comment: If you tell us what you're trying to do, perhaps we can show you how Beast does it best.

Comment: @sehe because in the stream might be present also non-http data, and i need process that stream asynchronously because i have many connections which do same things and just one thread call io_context.run method

Answer (score 1):

> I think it can be done using m_ssl_stream.async_read_some operation

I think the opposite. In fact all composed read operations (like `asio::async_read`) are **always** specified in terms of one or more `s.async_read_some` operations, which is actually the only operation specified on the [`AsyncReadStream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html) concept.

What you need to do is specify your intent. When you expect 20'000 bytes, why `transfer_at_least(1)`?

```
async_read(ssl_stream, m_buffer, asio::transfer_at_least(1), callback);
```

Could be

```
async_read(ssl_stream, m_buffer, asio::transfer_exactly(20'000), callback);
```

Also, when you don't know the expected size of payload (e.g. `Content-Length`), you can often use [`async_read_until` with a suitable condition/pattern](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html):

```
async_read_until(ssl_stream, m_buffer, "\r\n\r\n", callback);
```

Note that all versions with dynamic buffers may read *more* than satisfies the completion condition. However on completion `bytes_transferred` reflects the number of bytes satisfying the condition. Therefore the usual pattern would be:

```
 void callback(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
     if (ec.failed()) {
          // handle...
          return;
     }
     
     // use m_buffer...
     m_buffer.consume(bytes_transferred); // keeps remaining buffer content
 }
```

Comment: i can`t use asio::transfer_exactly(20'000) because data amount can be different (sometimes 5 bytes, sometimes 1000 bytes etc), Also i am aware about async_read_until, but some responses can contain a body and i need parse it with beast parser. Maybe i need do m_buffer.prepare(n) and do something like that m_ssl_stream.async_read_some(m_buffer.prepare(n), ...). It is ok?

Comment: prepare is works fine for me, but i am not have information about lifetime of the result of m_buffer.prepare(n). If m_buffer is class field, can i safely run operation like that m_ssl_stream.async_read_some(m_buffer.prepare(n), ...) in the class method and don`t care about buffer lifetime?

Comment: `prepare` is what composed operations will do in order to use `async_read_some` with a dynamic buffer, yes. You can never safely "don't care about lifetime". But, seeing that `m_ssl_stream` is **also** a member, no **extra** care has to be taken other than usual lifetime and thread-safety requirements. Note that manual `prepare()` implies manual `commit()`. I wouldn't use a dynamic buffer if you're going to great lengths to use it as static buffers. (Again, I think `*_some` interface is the opposite of what you're looking for)

Comment: Yes, i use m_buffer for the reading http and also for reading other raw data with async_read_some(m_buffer.prepare(n), ...), commit data in the callback, read it from the m_buffer and .consume the readed data from buffer. As i understand, lifetime of the buffer which returns by prepare depends of the lifetime of m_buffer and therefore result of .prepare should not be destroyed until the m_buffer is still "alive". Is my understanding correct? If yes, then i cannot understand why this approach can be a bad

Comment: I can't say whether your understanding is correct because you're describing things ambiguously. The result of `.prepare()` is obviously invalidated when `m_buffer` lifetime ends. However it is **also** invalidated in different circumstances. E.g. [see the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/DynamicBuffer_v1.html#:~:text=memory%20as%20required.-,All%20constant%20or%20mutable%20buffer%20sequences%20previously%20obtained%20using%20data()%20or%20prepare()%20are%20invalidated.,-Throws%3A%20length_error)

Comment: Also, buffer validity is not the goal. Efficient transfer is. `read_some` is most likely the interface you need. But you haven't really told us what you're trying to achieve, so I can't show you how I'd do it (if at all)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are help me a lot. I think i don`t need read_some, because it is a synchronous call. I need asynchronous call by design

Comment: Ugh. Obviously when I said `read_some` I meant the composed operation, `async_read_some` equally.